# R - combined geom_vline and geom_smooth in legend

Tags: r, ggplot2

I'm encountering some strange behaviour in my legend when adding a `geom_smooth()` and a `geom_vline()` in my ggplot2 chart. Here's a reproducible example:

```
library(ggplot2)
n <- 60

set.seed(123)
df <- data.frame(Area = sample(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), size = n, replace = TRUE),
             x = runif(n),
             y = runif(n),
             Type = sample(c("I", "II"), size = n, replace = TRUE),
             Result = sample(c("K", "L", "M"), size = n, replace = TRUE))

df.breaks <- data.frame(Area = c("B", "C"), x = c(0.8, 0.3))

ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
  geom_point(aes(colour = Result, shape = Type), size = 3) + 
  geom_smooth(aes(linetype = "Smooth"), colour = "green", se = FALSE) + 
  geom_hline(yintercept = 0.3) + 
  facet_wrap(~Area) + 
  geom_vline(data = df.breaks, aes(xintercept = x, linetype = "Break"), colour = "purple") + 
  scale_colour_manual(values = c("K" = "red", "L" = "orange", "M" = "blue")) + 
  scale_linetype_manual(name = "Lines", values = c("Break" = "dashed", "Smooth" = "solid"))
```

[image]

As you will notice the "Lines" legend has both the vertical and the horizontall lines in each item, and in the first case there are a couple of dashed lines while in the second case a couple of solid lines. I'm trying to adjust my code to produce a legend with (1) a horizontal green line and a key next to it called "Smooth" and (2) a vertical purple dahsed line with a key next to it called "Break". I would appreciate some help as, no matter what I tried (including `linetype` inside/outside `aes()` etc, or using `scale_linetype_identity()`, or even the `override.aes` option in `guides`) I couldn't find the right combination!

I searched for similar examples and even though I found other posts with a superimposed vertical line on `colour`, `fill`, or `shape` etc, I coulnd't find one with a vertical line on a `linetype` legend such as mine. Any help will be deeply appreciated! Thanks!

Comment: maybe this could help https://groups.google.com/forum/embed/#!topic/ggplot2/pv_CGdzPWnE

Comment: The only thing that I could figure out that even came close was to use `fill` for Smooth instead of `linetype` to create two separate legends.

Comment: Thank you to both of you for your answers. I went with @aosmith's suggestion which is simpler.

Comment: Cross posting without linking the 2 posts is considered ruse b/c someone may spend time to solve a problem already solved elsewhere.  http://www.talkstats.com/showthread.php/63630-A-question-on-legends

Comment: Apologies for that @TylerRinker . This was my first question on SO and I hadn't realised that I should link the two posts. Now, I know!

Comment: @aosmith Can you please put your comment as an answer so that I can accept it? If you don't want to spend any more time on it, what I used (based on your suggestion) was: `geom_smooth(aes(fill = "Smooth"), colour = "green", se = FALSE)` and worked with the two legends.

Comment: You can go ahead and answer your own question.  I don't remember too much about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A belated reply to this question but I thought it would be better to have an answer available in case someone else (or my future self!) is interested in this.

Following @aosmith's suggestion in the comments' section and his encouragement to provide the answer, I eventually replaced the code for the plot with:

```
ggplot(df, aes(x = x, y = y)) + 
     geom_point(aes(colour = Result, shape = Type), size = 3) + 
     geom_hline(yintercept = 0.3) + 
     facet_wrap(~Area) + 
     geom_vline(data = df.breaks, 
                aes(xintercept = x, linetype = "Break"), colour = "purple") + 
     scale_colour_manual(values = c("K" = "red", "L" = "orange", "M" = "blue")) + 
     scale_linetype_manual(name = "Lines",
                           values = c("Break" = "dashed", "Smooth" = "solid")) + 
     geom_smooth(aes(fill = "Smooth"), method = "loess", colour = "green", se = FALSE) + 
     scale_fill_discrete(name = "")
```

The last two lines above replace the following line from the original code:

`geom_smooth(aes(linetype = "Smooth"), colour = "green", se = FALSE) +`.

The resulting chart still needs some work, esepcially with the legend spacing, but it solves the original problem.

[image: Vertical and Horizontal Line Legend]