# Remove vertical line in legend caused by geom_vline in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2, aes, legend

I'm trying to fix up a legend so that there isn't a cross caused by the `geom_vline` in `ggplot`. 
I know my example doesn't make much sense as a plot, but just wanted a quick reproducible example.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds)+
  geom_point(aes(x = carat, y = depth, colour = "depth"), pch = 4)+
  geom_line(aes(x = carat, y = table, colour = "table"))+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 2, colour = "x = 2"))+
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype=c(0,1,1), shape=c(4,NA,NA))))
```

I know I can use `guide_legend(override.aes = …)` to fix  my issue with points and lines both appearing on each legend item but this does not appear to work to remove the vertical line created by `geom_vline()`

I have found several questions looking for a solution (below) but they all seem to solve it by separating the vline using a different aes (linetype or colours using fill). Is there a way I can keep the `colour` aes but not have my legend looking like this?

[R - combined geom_vline and geom_smooth in legend](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34797041/r-combined-geom-vline-and-geom-smooth-in-legend)

[Legend showing an unexpected black line with geom_vline](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29975176/legend-showing-an-unexpected-black-line-with-geom-vline)

[image]

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve with the colours. You used `aes` to map to the `depth` and `table` variables, but then you put those variable names in quotes, which does not map to the variables and instead has the effect of giving them a discrete colour.

Comment: Just want to note that this legend cross issue happens for geom_linerange as well. Setting 'show.legend=F' for geom_linerange and keeping other geom legends visible worked for me too.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This seems to work out for this example. Not sure about your actual data.

```
library(ggplot2)
ggplot(diamonds)+
  geom_point(aes(x = carat, y = depth, colour = "depth"), pch = 4)+
  geom_line(aes(x = carat, y = table, colour = "table"))+
  geom_vline(aes(xintercept = 2, colour = "x = 2"), show.legend = F)+
  guides(colour = guide_legend(override.aes = list(linetype=c(0,1,1), shape=c(4,NA,NA))))
```

[image]

Created on 2018-09-09 by the [reprex
package](http://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.2.0).

Comment: Perfect! I definitely thought if I set show.legend to FALSE that it wouldn't appear in the legend at all, slightly weird terminology there I think, but good to know. Thank you.

Comment: I honestly would have thought the same. I just gave it a shot and it looked good.